# How to get variable from the file via .get()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

A followed several examples, but I just can´t get it to work. After submiting the form I call this function:

```
function kontrola(){    
var jmeno = self.document.forms.newPassForm.user.value;
    $.get("checkMail.php?mail="+jmeno, function(jeObsazen){ 
        alert(jeObsazen); 
    }); 

return false;  
}
```

And PHP file, where content of *jeObsazen* variable is decided looks like this:

```
<?  
include "protected/_mysql.php";
$mail=$_GET['mail'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '".$mail."'");
$data=mysql_fetch_array($query);

if($data['id']==NULL) $jeObsazen = false;
else $jeObsazen = true;

?>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
var jeObsazen = <?echo $jeObsazen;?>
</script>
```

Only thing I want is to show in alert window, if variable jeObsazen is true or false. Now it alerts everything in  tags, included. Am I asking too much? :))

Thank you in advance for every help!

Comment: A php file with javascript inside it will not be interpreted. BTW, your script returns nothing

Comment: What data from the DB are you trying to return to `$.get` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to return something from your PHP script:

```
<?  
include "protected/_mysql.php";
$mail=$_GET['mail'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '".$mail."'");
$data=mysql_fetch_array($query);

if($data['id']==NULL) $jeObsazen = false;
else $jeObsazen = true;

echo $jeObsazen;
?>
```

And be aware `jeObsazen` in javascript will be a string, not a boolean

Comment: If I echo this, it returns 1 if mail is in DB, otherwise it returns nothing.

Comment: @MichalSirůček 1 is true, you are lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Before even continuing, add some error handling to make sure that your backend code is working. This includes checking the query for failure, and if it returned any rows:

```
if( $query === false ) {
    // query failed, details can be reached in mysql_error()
} else if( mysql_num_rows( $query ) ) {
    // no data returned
} else {
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
}
```

**NOTE:** Please remove the // comments and return a message in the event of a failure.

You will thank me for this later when you are wondering why nothing is being returned and the cause is no data in the db or a bad query!

Next, you dont need  tags in your php, it is unnecessary. You just need to dump out the variable:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if( $data['id'] != NULL ) {
    echo $data['id']; // this will return the id to your javascript $.get call
}
```

Here is what it looks like put together:

```
<?  
include "protected/_mysql.php";
$mail=$_GET['mail'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '".$mail."'");

if( $query === false ) {
    echo "Query failure";
} else if( mysql_num_rows( $query ) ) {
    echo "No data returned";
} else {
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    echo ( $data['id'] != NULL ); // returns 1 if user is not null, 0 otherwise
}

?>
```

Comment: Query works, Im using this piece of PHP in other place on my web and there is works. I also checked if variable for the query is passed correctly and it is. Problem is not in this for sure :/

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work, its just bad practice to have no error checking. There are many factors to cause it not to work in the future due to invalid data, or database connectivity issues.

If you read the answer again you will find that was just **one** of my points.

Comment: So is everything I need to do only to remove all the tags including the script in checkMail.php?

Comment: I removed the script and now it works, let´s say... btw isnt there any way how to access only chosen variable? Getting the data as string of everything echoed in php file doesn´t seem the best way to me... :/

Comment: The above echo does not return a string of everything, it returns the result of the `( $data['id'] != NULL )` statement which is only ever true, or false.

Another option is to just return true or false depending on how many rows the query returns. This way, you dont need to fetch data at all.